# How to make an npm package that peer dependent on react and react-dom

Tags: node.js, webpack

I made a npm package, and my package dependent on react and react-dom.
I don't want to pack them into the npm package so I made them as the externals:

```
  externals: {
    react: "react",
    "react-dom": "react-dom"
  }
```

By making them externals, I can package them without issue. But if I reference it in another project, it claims `can't find module 'react' and 'react-dom' even I am sure the react and react-dom are listed under the project's node_modules folder.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems by adding `peerDependency` in `package.json` can fix it:

```
peerDependency: {
    "react": "latest",
    "react-dom": "latest"
}
```